# Make project task tags scoped to the project's tags

Tags: python, tags, many-to-many, odoo-10

There is a model

```
class project_tag(models.Model):

    _name = 'project_tags.project_tag'
    _description = 'project_tag'

    name = fields.Char(string='Name', required=True, size=64)
```

Then there is project model

```
class project(models.Model):
    _inherit = 'project.project'

    project_tag_ids = fields.Many2many(
        'project_tags.project_tag',
        'project_project_tag_ids_rel',
        'project_id',
        'project_tag_id',
        string='Tags')
```

And finally a model

```
class ProjectTask(models.Model):
    """docstring"""
    _inherit = 'project.task'

    tag_ids = fields.Many2many(
        'project_tags.project_tag',
        'project_project_tag_ids_rel',
        'project_id',
        'project_tag_id',
        string='Tags',
        domain="[('project_id', 'in', project_id)]") .
```

The view for project task (model ProjectTask) contains field

```
<field name="tag_ids" widget="many2many_tags" options="{'no_create_edit': True}"/>
```

The user would like to see in tag_ids only those tags, that are configured for the project this task belongs to. For the given task's project there are no tags configured, so tag_ids should be empty but it's not :(.

Project tags (in this example it's empty).
[image]

I am hoping that domain would help. Unfortunately when tag_ids field definition is with domain

```
tag_ids = fields.Many2many(
        'project_tags.project_tag',
        'project_project_tag_ids_rel',
        'project_id',
        'project_tag_id',
        string='Tags',
        domain="[('project_id', 'in', project_id)]") .
```

the user sees an error

```
ValueError: Invalid field u'project_id' in leaf "<osv.ExtendedLeaf: (u'project_id', u'=', 10) on project_tags_project_tag (ctx: )>"
```

When without a domain it shows all the tags

```
tag_ids = fields.Many2many(
    'project_tags.project_tag',
    'project_project_tag_ids_rel',
    'project_id',
    'project_tag_id',
    string='Tags')
```

[image]

User expects to see only those tags that are assigned for the project.

The project manager can on the project window add tags to the project. The user that edits  or creates a task should be allowed to choose only those tags that are added for the project.

**How can I modify code so that tag_ids shows only those tags that are for the project_id the task belongs to?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up installing module [Project tags](https://apps.odoo.com/apps/modules/8.0/project_tags/). Then I configured project task to show only those tags to choose from, whose name is in the list of project tags.

:)

Answer (score 1):

Project tags are assigned by task, not project.  So your logic would have to be like tag_id.task_id.project_id = project_id.

I hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use this domain in the Python field definition

```
domain="[('project_id', 'in', project_id)]")
```

Because as the error states there is no context to be able to get the value of the field `project_id` as a variable for the `'in', project_id)]")` part of the domain. That is something that you could define it but in the xml view(where the view contains the project_id field too) instead of using it in the field definition.

```
<field name="project_id"/>    
<field name="tag_ids" widget="many2many_tags" domain="[('project_id', 'in', project_id)]" options="{'no_create_edit': True}"/>
```

The other error that I see is that your model `project_tags.project_tag` doesn't have the project_id field that you wanna filter in your domain, so at least that I'm not seeing the whole model definition that contain that field or you don't add it to the model, you won't be able to use that field in the domain.